# Angular 1 Select not Rendering Properly

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm writing an application using Python, Django and Angular 1, and having the strangest issue when the page is being rendered.

Here is HTML Snippet.  There are 4 sets of legend/input or legend/select, with the select being last.

```
<!-- tab 1 contents -->
<div ng-show="tab_1_active" style="height:90%;width:100%;overflow:auto;overflow-x:hidden;">

    <div id="tab_1_left" style="height:100%; width:33%">
        <div class="newRow" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <span class="input-header" style="width:100px;">Start Date:</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="activeProfile.startdate">
        </div>
        <div class="newRow" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <span class="input-header" style="width:100px;">LDA:</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="activeProfile.enddate">
        </div>
        <div class="newRow" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <span class="input-header" style="width:100px;">AY:</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="activeProfile.awardyear">
        </div>
        <div class="newRow" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <span class="input-header" style="width:100px;">AY:</span>
            <select ng-model="activeProfile.awardyear" ng-options="ay.display for ay in awardYears"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
input {
    height:35px;
    margin-top:5px;
}
.newRow {
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    }
select {font-size:14px; padding:6px;    background:none;    border:3px solid #727272;
    height:35px; 
    background:url(../images/arrow_down.png) 98% .4em no-repeat;
    -webkit-appearance: none;appearance: none;-moz-appearance: none;
    border-radius:0;-moz-border-radius:0; -webkit-border-radius:0;
    overflow:hidden; 
    padding-right:50px;
}
```

When the page renders as-is, everything looks fine.  Page and rendered html in developer tools look like the following:

[image]
[image]

Now, when I move the div with the select inside of it up 1 so it is the third instead of fourth item in the page, it gets all messed up.  Here are the new page and rendered HTML from developer tools:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the select field is no longer justified, the closing  tag for the third div is missing, as well as the opening div and span for the fourth div.  This happens no matter where in the list I put the div with the select.  The original HTML snippet is fine, but the Angular rendered HTML is all messed up.

Since I need to add other input fields on the form, as well as other select fields, I really need to solve this.  Can anybody see why the select field is messing up the field below it?  Thanks...

Comment: Would you mind posting the real code instead of screenshots? Also some runnable code would be nice (SO has a very neat feature for that). You can strip all the AngularJS stuff from the code since it doesn't seem to be any related to your CSS/layout problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new to this open source stuff.  The html is real, the css is real, the rendered html by angular is a screen shot because there is no way to copy it, so I could only take a shot of it.  I don't know why I got down-voted because of that.  Don't know what SO is.  Isn't Angular and how it renders the page the problem? How would stripping it out help? How can I supply runable code if it depends on my database? I want to be helpful, please advise.

Comment: Your problem seems to be related only to HTML and CSS, so in order to find the problem one would usually create a small sample from the generated code. The screenshots you provided essentially are such snippets - perfect size for debugging. You can easily copy the generated AngularJS code using the browser's developer tools (read about it and learn to use it - it's essential). Oh and SO means StackOverflow, the website you are currently on.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I took out the Angular stuff and just have an empty Select tag, and problem still occurs.  I will research how to give some runable code.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.
This:

```
<select ng-model="activeProfile.awardyear" ng-options="ay.display for ay in awardYears"/>
```

Should be:

```
<select ng-model="activeProfile.awardyear" ng-options="ay.display for ay in awardYears"></select>
```

I'm more used to working with XML, where that wouldn't make a difference.  Thanks @HubertGrzeskowiak for suggestions.